# Add a document listener for when DOM completely loads including lazy loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension and I would like to ready a property that only appears after an API response renders data on the page.

I'm using:

```
document.querySelector('td[data-testid="total-amount"]')?.innerHTML.trim()
```

but that information only loads after 10 seconds and returns undefined before the code is lazy loaded. I'm worried about a delay since it takes so long that it's likely the user will navigate away before we can read the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). First find any parent not-lazy-loaded element (the closer to your target the better). Then search for [a mutation adding your target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036689/using-mutationobserver-to-detect-when-a-node-is-added-to-document).

The simpler (but less efficient probably) solution would be to find `td[data-testid="total-amount"]` every `n` (probably 1?) second until found. You can use conditionally recursive [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [setInverval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) with [cleanInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) once found.

If the whole or most of the page is loaded dynamically and its structure is pretty complex I would recommend second option - as it may even turn out more performance-wise.